# Access of flag by CPU

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

Consider we are using a flag which takes a 0 or 1 value in a embedded programming. Thus we need only 1 bit. However when CPU access data it would access all the 8 bit associated with it. Is this a waste of CPU? Is there a technique to avoid this inefficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, Accessing a single bit requires reading the entire word, masking the single bit of interest then acting on the result.

Modifying a single bit required a read, mask and modify, ORing or ANDing depending setting or clearing then writing the result back. The so called "read-modify-write" action. Yes this is inefficient.

A solution called "[bit-banding](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/02/08/bit-banding/)" sets aside a region of memory whose address map to single bits primarily for peripherals.

I used this for the first time in the ARM Cortex-M3. Arm's solution is accessible in C-programming.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on CPU.

Some can access a single bit and some don't.

In any programming language you can store 8 flags per 8-bit byte yourself or with the help of the language if it supports the feature, e.g. C language bit fields.

If you have a lot of flags this may help so less memory is wasted. For a moder CPU with megabytes or gigabytes of memory it hardly matters, but for a small microcontroller with no RAM at all it may help to use the small amount of registers as storage.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CPU with an 8-bit bus will simply access 8 bits at a time, as part of a single memory operation which isn't divisible further. This is the case for anything from a tiny AVR that reads an 8-bit register even when you just care about one GPIO, to a high-end x86_64 CPU that will load a whole byte in a single `mov ... [byte ptr]` instruction, while possibly loading an entire cache line (as large as 64 bytes) into the L1 cache. This isn't an "inefficiency", per se - it's simplicity that allows better performance and better efficiency in the end.

It would require *much more* hardware and complexity to allow loading a single bit, while the underlying hardware is already offering data in a size that it can work with efficiently. Trying to subdivide the 8-bit bus of the AVR, or the cache lines and memory bus of the x86_64 CPU, would require a profound amount of extra circuitry, control complexity, and resulting silicon area/power consumption/speed penalties. As [RussellH's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/668269/9612) points out, some vendors have made the choice to support that functionality with its requisite complexity, but it's not a tradeoff that makes sense for all hardware.